# Extract From URL

Tags: python

How to extract da_dk part from the url? I am trying to find the country code and language code from url.

```
import re
url = https://www.url.com/content/test/abcd/da_dk/1234.html
#cc_lc = re.search(?, url)
cc ,lc = cc_lc.split(‘_’)
print(cc,lc)
```

Comment: Is it always the last thing before the filename?

Comment: @MoxieBall not always

Comment: Have you checked out furl? https://pypi.org/project/furl/

Comment: We don't know: you haven't specified the format your URLs use.

Comment: Url format is unknown; but for this url -> `url.rsplit('/', 2)[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
import re
url = "https://www.url.com/content/test/abcd/da_dk/1234.html"
url_list = url.split('/')
for el in url_list:
    if "_" in el:
        codes = el.split("_")
        if (len(codes) == 2):
            #use regex to check coade[0] and code[1] are valid cc and lc or not
```